# How do I tell whether a Type implements IList<>?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

I want to write a method that uses Reflection to tell whether a given Type implements `IList<T>`. For example:

```
IsGenericList(typeof(int))                       // should return false
IsGenericList(typeof(ArrayList))                 // should return false
IsGenericList(typeof(IList<int>))                // should return true
IsGenericList(typeof(List<int>))                 // should return true
IsGenericList(typeof(ObservableCollection<int>)) // should return true
```

In my usage, I can assume that the type will always be an instantiated generic type (or something that's not generic at all).

Unfortunately, this isn't as easy as it ought to be. The obvious solution:

```
public bool IsGenericList(Type type)
{
    return typeof(IList<>).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

doesn't work; it always returns false. Apparently non-instantiated generic types like `IList<>` don't implement IsAssignableFrom the way I'd expect them to: `IList<>` is not assignable from `List<T>`.

I've also tried this:

```
public bool IsGenericList(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsGenericType)
        return false;
    var genericTypeDefinition = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    return typeof(List<>).IsAssignableFrom(genericTypeDefinition);
}
```

I.e., turn `type` into its non-instantiated generic, like `IList<int>` -> `IList<>`, and then try IsAssignableFrom again. That will return true when type is an instantiated `IList<T>` such as `IList<int>`, `IList<object>`, etc. But it returns false for classes that implement `IList<T>` such as `List<int>`, `ObservableCollection<double>`, etc., so apparently `IList<>` is not assignable from `List<>`. Again, not what I would expect.

How do I go about writing IsGenericList and making it work as in the above examples?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In fact, you cannot have an instance of a generic type definition. Therefore, the IsAssignableFrom() method works as expected. To achieve what you want, do the following:

```
public bool IsGenericList(Type type)
{
    if (type == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
    }
    foreach (Type @interface in type.GetInterfaces()) {
        if (@interface.IsGenericType) {
            if (@interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>)) {
                // if needed, you can also return the type used as generic argument
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Just out of curiosity, what do you need this for?

Comment: +1 - This works, and is the only solution here that currently does - I just realized you had this after I posted the same thing.

Comment: Never saw @ to use keywords as variable names in any production code before.

Comment: Good solution. :) Small point however: using the @ symbols is generally not recommended practice. (You could just call the variable `i` or `curInterface` instead to resolve the name clash.)

Comment: ReSharper gave that identifier this name when I auto-expanded the foreach on type.GetInterfaces() - I usually don't use that feature either when choosing names myself. But I wanted to be quick so I didn't refactor it. ;)

Comment: You're missing the { for the method and you used ICollection<> instead of IList<>, but otherwise this works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: As for why we need this: we're translating code from Delphi/Win32 to C#/.NET, and our workarounds for Delphi fixed-size arrays don't play nice with our workarounds for test-framework resource cleanup, so we're deciding whether to add yet another workaround for the combination, and I want to know how often that workaround would need to apply. Specifically, I need a one-off tool to tell me how many test-case classes have fields whose types implement IList or IList<T>. Aren't you glad you asked? (grin)

Comment: I used this when reflecting over fields and properties on a type and re-setting them back to default values (null for reference types). For Lists I wanted to set them back to empty lists rather than null.

Comment: Careful @JoeWhite, if you replace `ICollection` with `IList` then  `IsGenericList(typeof(IList<int>))` will return False. Fix below http://stackoverflow.com/a/13589104/284795

Answer (score 18):

I too want to test if a type implements `IList<T>` for some T. I made the obvious change to [Lucero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/951602/284795) but it caused a [subtle bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951536/how-do-i-tell-whether-a-type-implements-ilist/13589104#comment18625777_951602) not present in the original answer. Here's my final edit:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Test if a type derives from IList of T, for any T.
    /// </summary>
    public bool TestIfGenericList(Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("type");
        }

        var interfaceTest = new Predicate<Type>(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>));

        return interfaceTest(type) || type.GetInterfaces().Any(i => interfaceTest(i));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's indeed better than the accepted answer as it works for `IList<T>` itself.

Answer (score 2):

Lucero/Reed Copsey both have the right solution now. Just to make it more concise, here it is in LINQified form:

```
var isGenericList = type.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && 
    t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>));
```

Comment: Won't work, since GetInterfaces() will not return the generic type definitions, only the generic types (such as IList<int>).

Comment: Yeah, so it doesn't. I've updated it and it seems to work now however.

Comment: You can rewrite my solution using Linq if you want... ;)

Comment: I didn't choose Linq because from the question it is only clear that generic are available, not what version of the C# compiler is being used.

Comment: It fails again for case #3 ... have a look at my solution - shorter and faster

Comment: Lucero's solution seems more robust, as it doesn't involve strings.

Answer (score 2):

Using this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.findinterfaces.aspx

I tried this:

```
 public class Test : IList<string>
 {
//implementation left out...
 }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            TypeFilter myFilter = new TypeFilter(MyInterfaceFilter);

            Type type = t.GetType();
            Type[] x = type.FindInterfaces(myFilter, "System.Collections.Generic.IList");
            Console.WriteLine(x.Length);

        }

        public static bool MyInterfaceFilter(Type typeObj, Object criteriaObj)
        {
            if (typeObj.ToString().Contains(criteriaObj.ToString()))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a non-strong-name to identify a type is very unsafe. Anyone can create a type with that name, it doesn't mean that it's the type you want to test for.

Comment: True, you could just replace it with this:
Type[] x = type.FindInterfaces(myFilter, typeof(IList<>).FullName);

Answer (score 1):

This passes your tests ...

```
public static bool IsGenericList( Type type )
{
  return type.Name == "IList`1" || type.GetInterface( "IList`1" ) != null;
}
```

Comment: type doesn't have to be generic to implement a generic interface. You can have this: class IntList: object, IList<int> { .... } which doesn't make IntList generic.

Comment: The IsGeneric check is not neccessary at all

Answer (score 1):

I liked [Colonel Panic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13589104/184528), but I decided to make the answer a bit more generic so I could reuse it another scenarios:

```
    public static bool InstanceOfGenericType(this Type self, Type genericType)
    {
        return self.IsGenericType && self.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType;
    }

    public static bool InstanceOfGenericInterface(this Type self, Type ifaceType)
    {
        return self.InstanceOfGenericType(ifaceType) 
            || self.GetInterfaces().Any(i => i.InstanceOfGenericType(ifaceType));
    }

    public static bool IsIList(this Type t)
    {
        return t.InstanceOfGenericInterface(typeof(IList<>));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling [Type.GetInterface()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayfa0fcd.aspx)? It's not completely clear from the help, but I think that it will search interfaces implemented by base types, in addition to the type itself. If not, you can always loop through `Type.BaseType` and call `GetInterface()` again.

Comment: GetInterface only works if you know the specific generic argument, but won't work for IList<T>.

Answer (score -3):

Use the "[is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.71).aspx)" operator:

> The is operator is used to check
>   whether the run-time type of an object
>   is compatible with a given type.

Comment: I don't have an instance. I have the Type.

Comment: This won't work with IList<>, only with IList<int>, etc.  You need to have a concrete type for "is" to work...

Comment: You need an instance for `is`. The OP asked how to do the check using a `Type`.